# Disable three finger drag on Xcode

Tags: xcode, trackpad, defaults

I want to use the three finger vertical swipe to switch between header and implementation files on Xcode, but this stops working when I have three finger drag enabled in system preferences.

I've tried using `defaults write` with some trial and error, but am unable to get it to work.

Looking for something like this:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode com.Apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad.TrackpadThreeFingerDrag 0
```

Comment: If You do not want to have conflicts with Free Finger Drag, in Better Touch Tool You can assign "Three Finger Clickwipe" (touchpad needs to be pressed) to ⌘⌃↑ in Xcode switch between .h/.m files.

Comment: Is it imperative you use three finger drag elsewhere? Personally, I hate it, and prefer the old double-tap-n-drag behaviour so I switch mine back to that.

Comment: @StuartH thanks, but I am in love with three finger drag and am not willing to let it go :)